# How to create a cookie on form submitting?

Tags: php

i have a light box form i want to create a cookie when user submitting that form...my cookie variables are  setCookie("username",username,1000) i want to do this while user submitting the form...thanks..!

Your Full Name:

```
<p>Your Facebook Email Or Username: 
  <input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="60" size="60">
</p>
```

Comment: can u show your code, what u try till now

Comment: please specify if you want to achieve this in JavaScript or PHP and either before/or after the form is sent

Comment: <input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="setCookie("username",username,1000)">

Comment: after user fills the form , when he clicks Submit button i need to create a cookie...i just wants to create a cookie in these variables setCookie("username",username,1000) but that cookie will be checked with JAVA..

Comment: according to question in here i tryed... input type="submit" name="submit" onsubmit="alert("alert")"> but its not working.....

Comment: @Navi you got any error then post the error . IF you got any error then edit your question so it will be more clear to community members where is the problem ?/

Comment: <div id="shadowing"></div>
<div id="box">
  <span id="boxtitle"></span>
  <form method="GET" action="info.php" target="_parent">
 <p>Your Full Name: 
      <input type="text" name="name" value="" maxlength="60" size="60">
    </p>
      
    <p>Your Facebook Email Or Username: 
      <input type="text" name="email" value="" maxlength="60" size="60">
    </p>
      
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO IN">

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `lightbox` is opened...

```
$('.lightbox').click( function() {

    $.post('save_cookie.php');

});
```

And `save_cookie.php`:

```
setcookie(...);
```

I did it with PHP because your only tag is `php`. You can do it with only `javascript` too.

P.S. I used `jQuery` here too.

Answer (score 1):

When you are submitting a form and redirecting it to your main page, at the top of that you can write code to set cookie ..

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
  {
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}